# How to Refactor R.java's package in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, package, r.java-file

I want to rename my Android project's package name. Under `src/` folder refactoring of packages successful but if want to rename package under `gen/` folder I can't do it. Because there is `R.java` file there. It is recreating *automatically* itself. If I disable this issue from `Project -> Build Automaticall` option then I see new problems with other java files.

Shortly

How can I rename my package name in Eclipse correctly and without error?

Comment: Did you try to change the package name in the Android Manifest file?

Comment: yes, already Eclipse did it for me. Also I checked it. Manifest file is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has solved. This is stupid Eclipse issue. Sometimes it could not understand changes. I restarted Eclipse, clenead project then everything is ok.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application Package.
You can also change the package name on the manifest and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

Depends really on how you set up things.

The correct way to rename would be to allow eclipse do manually update all the package references:

Try:

```
Right-hand click on resource > Refactor > Rename
```

Comment: Yes i did same, but it is giving error. After refactor/reneme happening to package old package and new named package

Comment: Note sure I understand, did you clean your project? R.java is generated, so it should be auto-generated again.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps given below to rename packages in the gen folder.

1. Right click on the package under gen folder
2. Select Refactor
3. Select Rename
4. Now change your package name as you wish
5. Make sure you check the following options when you rename

   - Update references
   - Rename subpackages

[image]

6. Click Ok
7. Now click on your Manifest file
8. Select the Manifest Tab
9. You will notice the package option
10. Rename it to the name you want.

[image]

11. Now clean and build the project